# How to change Button Color and Name in specific cell in Material UI Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am using  `Material  Table` for Showing my Data.
Here it looks like,
https://i.postimg.cc/4x6hbm5N/image.png

I have declared a `state` above in my code

```
const [sharedOrdersList, setShareOrdersList] = useState([])
```

When the `User` click the `Share` button, I will push the `Order Id` to `sharedOrdersList`. It works. But now my issue was i want to change the  Button Name to `UnShare` and button color to another color. I tried several ways. But I don't know how to make it

Here's my Function Code:

```
 const shareOrderBtnClick = (orderID) => {
    sharedOrdersList.push(orderID)

    alert("share Btn Clicked")
    console.log(sharedOrdersList)
  }
```

Return Code:

```
allOrderDatas.map((row) => (
        <TableRow>
         <TableCell">
                <Button variant="contained" 
                  onClick={()=>{shareOrderBtnClick(row.orderID)}}
                   style={{ backgroundColor:sharedOrdersList.includes(row.orderID)?"#59886B":"#D54062",}}> 
    <ShareIcon />{sharedOrdersList.includes(row.orderID)?"UnShare":"Share"</Button>
          </TableCell>
         </TableRow>
```

I don't know how to change the specific item in the cell in the row in table. Please Help me with some solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

states in react are immutable. `useState` returns a value and an updater function. You can't directly change the value.
To update the state you need to call `setShareOrdersList` function with the new value.

In you're example

```
const shareOrderBtnClick = (orderID) => {
    setShareOrdersList([... sharedOrdersList, orderID]); 
// OR BETTER
//   setShareOrdersList(prevState => [...prevState, orderID]);
  }
```